# Squid transparent proxy for HTTPS requests that have been redirected by DNAT rule

Tags: iptables, proxy, https, squid, ssl-bump

I would like to look into suspicious activity of possibly infected web application in my network. I wanted to use squid to intercept https requests with `https_port` directive.

My network setup:
http/https requests are normally sent to the gateway host without any proxy setup on the client side. On the gateway they're redirected from their original destination IP/port to proxy host with iptables rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -s CLIENT_IP -j DNAT --to-destination PROXY_IP:3128
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -s CLIENT_IP -j DNAT --to-destination PROXY_IP:3130
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d CLIENT_IP -j MASQUERADE
```

On the proxy server the squid with version 4.13 is installed and these options are included:

```
...
 --with-gnutls \
 --with-openssl \
 --enable-ssl \
 --enable-ssl-crtd \
```

The squid config:

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports

acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all

http_port 3128
http_port 3129 intercept

https_port 3130 intercept ssl-bump tls-cert=/etc/squid/cert/myCA.pem dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=16MB generate-host-certificates=on 

sslcrtd_program /usr/lib/squid/security_file_certgen -s /var/lib/squid/ssl_db -M 16MB

acl step1 at_step SslBump1

ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump bump all
ssl_bump splice all

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

- I added another redirection rule, this time on proxy server:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3128 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3129
```

This fixed http intercepting and my attempts from the clients with curl towards http websites are working. Similiar setup did not fix https intercepting, actually it has never reached the origin server, with the squid setup above the access logs print these lines if I attempt `curl -v https://stackexchange.com/` :

```
1692864790.326      5 CLIENT_IP TCP_DENIED/200 0 CONNECT PROXY_IP:3130 - HIER_NONE/- -
1692864790.331      0 CLIENT_IP NONE/403 3791 GET https://stackexchange.com/ - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

I know it's denied because the port is not allowed in http_access rules but it should not go to proxy_ip at all. I tested various ssl_bump directives options but none of them make ssl communication work.

e.g. when 3130 port is allowed it ends in loop

```
1692871715.986  60813 CLIENT_IP NONE/200 0 CONNECT PROXY_IP:3130 - ORIGINAL_DST/PROXY_IP -
1692871715.986  60807 PROXY_IP NONE/200 0 CONNECT PROXY_IP:3130 - ORIGINAL_DST/PROXY_IP -
1692871715.986  60807 PROXY_IP NONE/200 0 CONNECT PROXY_IP:3130 - ORIGINAL_DST/PROXY_IP -
1692871715.986  60807 PROXY_IP NONE/200 0 CONNECT PROXY_IP:3130 - ORIGINAL_DST/PROXY_IP -
1692871715.986  60806 PROXY_IP NONE/200 0 CONNECT PROXY_IP:3130 - ORIGINAL_DST/PROXY_IP -
1692871715.986  60806 PROXY_IP NONE/200 0 CONNECT PROXY_IP:3130 - ORIGINAL_DST/PROXY_IP -
1692871715.986  60806 PROXY_IP NONE/200 0 CONNECT PROXY_IP:3130 - ORIGINAL_DST/PROXY_IP -
1692871715.986  60805 PROXY_IP NONE/200 0 CONNECT PROXY_IP:3130 - ORIGINAL_DST/PROXY_IP -
1692871715.986  60805 PROXY_IP NONE/200 0 CONNECT PROXY_IP:3130 - ORIGINAL_DST/PROXY_IP -
1692871715.986  60805 PROXY_IP NONE/200 0 CONNECT PROXY_IP:3130 - 
...
...
```

Only scenario when `https_port` listener works and the client reached the destination was when I used env. variables on client side: `https_proxy=https://PROXY_IP:3130/` and https_port is in default forward proxy mode / without intecept ssl-bump /
But I don't want to use env. variables , I need transparent proxying.

### My analysis to this problem and question:

the DNAT redirections rules on gateway hosts change destination IPs of the https packets and squid can't set the original one back and keeps sending them to proxy IP which makes the weird access.log records above. I know squid is able to fix it for http packets with additional redirection rule, but not for https.

I read lot of similiar issues on various forums and tried to adapt their config but no solution fixed my problem and I think it's because all tutorials expect that clients are sending requests to the proxy as their default gateway and not using DNAT rules on them on third host like it is in my case.

Please do you know if there is solution in squid to use original destination IP from header for https packet insted of "spoofed" one or some other option to fix the packets?

Thank you for any kind of insight.